# Error when trying to AWS command line associate alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, serverless-aws-alias

I'm trying to associate an aws alias to a distribution, I currently have 2 distributions:

disbtA  with an alternate domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

disbtB no alternate domain setup lets give it an id of 123

aws cloudfront associate-alias --target-distribution-id 123 --alias [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I get the error:

An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the AssociateAlias operation: Invalid or missing alias DNS TXT records.

They are both on the same account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missing this step:

Create a DNS TXT record that associates the alternate domain name with the distribution domain name of the target distribution. Create your TXT record with an underscore (_) in front of the alternate domain name. The following shows an example TXT record in DNS:

_[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) TXT d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net

CloudFront uses this TXT record to validate your ownership of the alternate domain name.

Comment: but what in this case if I want to create a record with the same name as HZ, like "example.com" ->  d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net